# JavaScript override from a non ES6 class to an ES6 class

Tags: javascript, es6-class

In my Webapp I need to implement an API, which does not contain any ES6 class definitions, but I would like to extend of one of these classes and override some methods. Overriding does not work properly...

```js
function A() {
  this.msg = function() {
    console.log("A");
  }
}

class B {
  constructor() {
    A.call(this);
  }

  msg() {
    console.log("B");
  }
}

new B().msg();
```

I expect "B" as result but the method of "class" A gets executed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that in `A`, the `msg` function is attached to `this` *in the constructor* - that is, the `msg` property is attached *directly to the instance object itself*, not on the prototype. In contrast, the `msg` of `B` is on the *prototype* of `B` - that is, `B.prototype`, the object that the instance inherits from.

One option would be to overwrite `msg` in `B`'s constructor:

```js
function A() {
  this.msg = function() {
    console.log("A");
  }
}

class B {
  constructor() {
    A.call(this);
    this.msg = () => {
      console.log('b');
    }
  }
}

new B().msg();
```

A nicer looking prototypal solution would be for `B` to extend `A`, if that's a possible modification you can make:

```js
function A() {
  // empty constructor
}
A.prototype.msg = function() {
  console.log("A");
}

class B extends A {
  msg() {
    console.log('b');
  }
}

new B().msg();
```

(with this, the internal prototype chain looks like: `A.prototype -> B.prototype -> instance`, so from the instance, `B.prototype.msg` takes priority over `A.prototype.msg`)

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not able to change the class definitions/constructor of the api-classes. So willy-nilly the workaround needs to be the definition in the constructor...